# how to build deb packages in the desired directory when I compile the kernel?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, kernel, ubuntu-14.04

I trying to build deb packages in other output directory than a previous folder i only know this option for ubuntu :

```
make deb-pkg
```

but this command creates the packages in a previous folder, but i need to automated this process for this reason i need that the deb packages in other output directory, the command deb-pkg is not necessary, i mean i can try with other commands that works on ubuntu and it does the job desired.
I appreciate your help on this

thanks

Comment: just had a short look at the `dpkg-buildpackage` manpage. with option `-T` you are able to call a target specified in `debian/rules` from which you are probably able to initiate your build and move your files afterwards "manually".